# APK is installing but the app does not show up in the app list nor is the normal open option available

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have a react-native app which I need to distribute, however our distributors are complaining that the app will install on their android device but the app will not show in the list of apps available to run nor is the open option available when freshly installed. The app only shows in the apps list in settings to uninstall.

My manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:pathPrefix="/${applicationId}/android/callback"
                android:scheme="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried enabling the universal architecture, changing the keystore, even trying a new installation of the project but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

In your `intent-filter`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was solved by putting in another intent filter with the code you listed. Tysm